# C# CSV reader that can handle truncated rows?

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, csv, sqlcommand

Best practice question:

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
1,2,3

1,,3

,2,3

,,3

1

1

1
```

I want it to go into SQL:

```
1,2,3

1,null,3

null,2,3

null,null,3

1,null,null

1,null,null

1,null,null
```

The last three rows are giving me problems. Without the correct number of commas, my "cmd.Parameters.Add" throws an exception: IndexOutOfRangeException when no value has been assigned to that location in the array. I would like it to just pass null values like it already does for instances where a comma delimits an empty space.

```
while
{
string parts = new string[10];
parts = parser.ReadFields();
if (parts==null)
{break};

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@one",SqlDbType.Int).Value = parts[0];
cmd.Parameters.Add("@two",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = parts[1];
cmd.Parameters.Add("@three",SqlDbType.Float).Value = parts[2];

[run cmd]
```

How should I be doing this? I have a couple hundred parameters, so avoiding a solution where I test every single value for null and then apply DBNull.Value would be best if possible. Is this [string parts = new string[10];] my problem? Is there a better way to declare this array that will avoid these exceptions?

Comment: You problem is accessing `parts[0..n]` when your `ReadFields` method doesn't return an array with 10 parts... Can you show that function's code ?

Comment: You could use `parts.ElementAtOrDefault(1)`

Comment: @Bun: i will ad it in, but its using the built-in VS TextFieldParser.

Comment: @Tim: It does not seem to allow me to set the default value as null?

Comment: You have lost me, the default value of string is null.

Comment: @Tim: indeed, but when I try to assign the parameter to parts[2] it throws an exception if the CSV import did not get to parts[2] before reaching the end of the line. It basically says I cannot do that because my array does not have enough elements...theres not even a spot for the null to go. I am very new to programming in general, so I might not be making sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string parts = new string[10];` is *wrong* (it should just be `string[] parts;`). I'm amazed that compiles, with the mismatch between the declared and assigned types.

But it's not the problem here.

Try changing this line:

```
if (parts==null)
```

to this:

```
if (parts==null || parts.Length < 3)
```

Or, if you need those rows:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@one",SqlDbType.Int).Value = parts[0];
cmd.Parameters.Add("@two",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = parts[1] ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@three",SqlDbType.Float).Value = parts[2] ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: I could not get the ?? function to work in my situation, but the OR  did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply use [`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or check the `Length` of the `string[]`?

```
string value = parts.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
if(value == null)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@two",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
else
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@two",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = value;
```

Comment: You can use the null coalescing operator to sub in `DBNull` for `null`

Comment: @Servy: i wasn't sure if that compiles. **Edit** It does not: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@two", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = value ?? DBNull.Value;`

Comment: yeah, you might need a cast to `object` in there.  Of course, you can just create a new extension method to support it as well, which is likely worth doing.

Comment: @ Servy & Tim: I attempted the same command as Tim wrote out, but it wouldn't compile. I am afraid I am not really sure what the coalesce operator is doing. I will research it.